# Calculating the pH of soft drink

Tags: everyday-chemistry, ph, titration

Me and my classmates are doing an experiment in order to determine the pH of Sprite. We are going to conduct a titration with NaOH.

We are taking under consideration that the citric acid in Sprite is the only thing that is causing the drink to be acidic.

Our question is how do we calculate the pH of the drink.
We determined that it took 26,9 ml of NaOH to make the solution of sprite (50ml) and water (50ml) neutral (pH=7).

Comment: Recall what the definition of pH is, and apply that definition to the system (Sprite before titration).

Comment: Do you know the concentration of the NaOH solution?

Comment: the concentration of NaOH is 0,1 M

Comment: Do a test when cold and bubbly and then boil to drive the bubbles out, allow to cool, and re-test.  You will be able to determine the effect of the carbonic acid.